# Why does a Qt application only create window handles if Spy++ is running?

Tags: c, windows, qt, winapi

I'm trying to automate an old Qt 4 application (for which I don't have the source code). If I run the application *before* running Spy++, Qt does not create window handles for child widgets. If I run the application *after* Spy++, window handles are created for child widgets like buttons and I can find them with `FindWindow`.

What is Spy++ doing to make Qt create child window handles and how can I do that in my own program?

Comment: Try [Wincheat](http://alinconstantin.dynu.com/Download/WinCheat/). It's a kind of Spy++ on steroids.

Comment: Re. forcing creation of native windows in your own program see [Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets).

Comment: If you want to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). You'll quickly learn that the question you asked is of no technical relevance with respect to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable Your comment is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Indeed. That's mostly because your question isn't relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm asking why Qt creates window handles for widgets only when Spy++ is running. I'm not asking for your opinion on *why I need to know that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Update:* just saw that @G.M. provides a link to documentation that also answers this.)

After some searching, I *think* I know why this happens.

It happens, because you do it ;-)

Spy++ apparently sends `WM_GETOBJECT` window message to the application, just like [Microsoft Active Accessiblity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/how-active-accessibility-works) would.

Qt, is smart enough to [intercept those messages](https://support.smartbear.com/testleft/docs/using/configuring/desktop-apps/qt/preparing-alien-widgets-for-testing.html) and [adjust](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/kernel/qapplication_win.cpp#L2363) accordingly, i.e. not using alien widgets, but native ones - <strike>because the lightweight/alien ones are not visible to the Windows accessibility machinery.</strike> *(Apparently, this was a wrong assumption as pointed out by @IInspectable's comment; thanks)*

In other words you cannot use Spy++ to look at non-native widgets with Qt.
The logic works both ways: you cannot do it because Spy++ causes Qt to use native widgets; even if it did not (Qt had no WM_GETOBJECT-handling), you wouldn't see any childwindows for Qt widgets, because there wouldn't be any (native ones).

Comment: Excellent. I figured Spy++ was doing something to trigger the accessibility API in Qt, but couldn't find what it was. Thank you!

Comment: MSAA/UIA does not rely on native window handles. It operates purely on interfaces provided by the accessible tree. It's not like Edge or Firefox would suddenly switch modes and suddenly invent native windows for their window-less UI just to turn accessible. They are accessible by virtue of implementing the accessible interfaces. This answer may address the question asked, though the rationale provided is off target.